# How to collect the COUNT(*) of two Distinct queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried the following query and got an error in MySQL. I kind of know why it's throwing me a syntax error (it's related to the two DISTINCT queries being run on the same line) but still believe that its possible (somehow). The two columns `card_type` and `split_type` each contain one of five values ("Attack", "Foundation", "Character", "Asset", "Action"). What I would like to do is create a query that would count a record as a +1 if "Attack" appeared in either `card_type` or `split_type`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ufs.card_type), DISTINCT(ufs.split_type), COUNT(*) AS COUNT
    FROM jg1_products p 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_product_types pt ON p.products_type = pt.type_id 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_products_to_categories ptc ON p.products_id = ptc.products_id 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_cards_ufs ufs ON ufs.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE type_handler LIKE "%product_cards%"
    AND ptc.categories_id = 89
GROUP BY ufs.card_type
```

I guess I should be a BIT clearer in my explanation:

I was hoping that the SQL query would return the total number of results which have met a condition in either Column A or Column B.

EXAMPLE: 
If the word "Attack" appeared in either column A or column B, count that as one.

If the word "Attack" appeared in Column A but Column B contains the word "Foundation", That would be +1 to Attack and +1 to Foundation.

In the end, the function/SQL would return to number of times that word (either of the five possibles) would appear between those two columns. So in short I used the "DISTINCT" command (incorrect I'll add) so that all the distinct values in column A are returned and the same for B. If they match, count that as one.

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL's aggregate [`SUM()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) function?

Comment: Not sure how I would use `sum()` since they are non-numerical values. Unless, you mean do two `SELECT` queries and do a sum with that?

Comment: You could try that, sure. Your question's title might have misled me, that's why I suggested it.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking here. Are you trying to make the first query work, or the one that's shown in your screenshot? (The select clauses are different.) It looks like you didn't finish your sentence in the first paragraph: "I kind of know why but I..."; it'd be helpful to see the rest of that sentence along with the error message you got from MySQL. You could edit the question to include both.

Comment: Question edited and I removed the SUM mention from the title to DISTINCT instead. Again what I'm trying to do is collect the total distinct records that match each other. For example "Attack" in either referenced column would count as a +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** "a query that would count a record as a +1 if "Attack" appeared in either card_type or split_type."

**A:** It's not clear what resultset you want to return.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment/clarification, if I'm understanding this correctly, if the rows returned by the SELECT were something like this example:

```
card_type  split_type
---------  -----------
Attack     Attack
Attack     Foundation
Attack     Crescendo
Foundation Foundation
```

You want a resultset something like this:

```
Attack     3
Foundation 2
Crescendo  1
```

You want 3 returned for "Attack", because three rows had the value `'Attack'` in either `card_type` or `split_type`. That is, you *don't* want to return a count of 4, the number of times the value appeared.

To get that result, using a `COUNT` aggregate, I would run this as two separate queries, and combine the results of the two queries using a `UNION ALL` set operator. The first query would get a count by just `card_type`, the second query would get a count by `split_type`. The "trick" would be for the second query to *exclude* any rows where the `split_type` matches the `card_type`.

The two combined queries would be used as an inline view, the outer query would combine the separate counts using a `SUM()` aggregate function.

I would do the query using a form something like this:

```
SELECT c.type
     , SUM(c.cnt) AS cnt
  FROM ( SELECT ufs.card_type AS `type`
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt 
           FROM ...

          GROUP BY ufs.card_type

          UNION ALL

         SELECT ufs.split_type AS `type`
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM ...

            AND NOT (ufs.split_type <=> ufs.card_type)
          GROUP BY ufs.split_type    
       ) c
 GROUP BY c.type
```

You'd plug in the row source of the original query two times, replacing the `...` in the query above.

---

**Previous answer:**

Assuming that you have a SELECT that returns the rows you want checked, one "trick" is to use an expression in the SELECT list to perform a conditional test, and return either a zero or one, and then use `SUM()` aggregate to return a "count" of the records that meet the specification..

```
SELECT SUM(IF(ufs.card_type LIKE '%Attack%' OR ufs.split_type LIKE '%Attack%',1,0)) AS cnt
  FROM jg1_products p 
  LEFT JOIN jg1_product_types pt ON p.products_type = pt.type_id 
  LEFT JOIN jg1_products_to_categories ptc ON p.products_id = ptc.products_id 
  LEFT JOIN jg1_cards_ufs ufs ON ufs.products_id = p.products_id
 WHERE type_handler LIKE "%product_cards%"
   AND ptc.categories_id = 89
```

This query returns a single row, unlike your original query that returns multiple rows. (Again, it's not clear what resultset you want returned; if you actually want to return a count for each distinct `card_type`, which would be returned if we included a `GROUP BY ufs.card_type` clause.

MySQL also provides a convenient shorthand for the boolean expression: the evaluation of a boolean expression returns 1 if TRUE, 0 if FALSE, and NULL if NULL. So this expression:

```
SELECT SUM(ufs.card_type LIKE '%Attack%' OR ufs.split_type LIKE '%Attack%')
  FROM ...
```

is equivalent to the expression in the query above, except for the handling of NULL values.

It's not clear whether you want to check if the column "contains" the string `'Attack'` as part of the string, or is the entire string; to check if the value of the column is exactly equal to `'Attack'`, use the equality comparison instead of `LIKE`

```
SELECT SUM(ufs.card_type = 'Attack' OR ufs.split_type = 'Attack') AS cnt
  FROM ...
```

---

**NOTE**

**`DISTINCT`** is not a function, it's a keyword.

The valid syntax is  **`SELECT DISTINCT expr1, expr2, ... exprN FROM ...`**.

It's invalid to include the `DISTINCT` keyword multiple times after the SELECT keyword, or in a position other than immediately following `SELECT`.  (The `DISTINCT` keyword can also be included the `COUNT()` aggregate function, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`, but that's entirely different than `SELECT DISTINCT`.

The parens are entirely ignored. That is, `SELECT DISTINCT(foo)` is identical to `SELECT DISTINCT foo`. Including parens is entirely unnecessary, and makes it look like DISTINCT is a function (which it is not.)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear in that manner. I was hoping that the SQL query would return the total number of results which have met a condition in either Column A or Column B. For example, if the word "Attack" appeared in either column A or column B, count that as one.

If the word Attack appeared in Column A but Column B contains the word "Foundation", That would be +1 to Attack and +1 to Foundation.

In the end, the function/SQL would return to number of times that word (either of the five possibles) would appear between those two columns.

Comment: Your edit to your answer actually works better than the result I tried to get with PHP. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ufs.card_type, ufs.split_type, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
    FROM jg1_products p 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_product_types pt ON p.products_type = pt.type_id 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_products_to_categories ptc ON p.products_id = ptc.products_id 
    LEFT JOIN jg1_cards_ufs ufs ON ufs.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE type_handler LIKE "%product_cards%"
    AND ptc.categories_id = 89
GROUP BY ufs.card_type
```

here query will select unique records from `card_type` and `split_type`

For more [Link](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php) can help you.

Comment: I'm getting closed with the content that you linked. (Specifically from what is in the section "COUNT() function and SELECT with DISTINCT on multiple columns"

- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php#sthash.zjqiZoUy.dpuf) This is what I'm trying to do but instead of just off one column, as two.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ufs.rarity)) AS COUNT ...
```

Enjoy your code!